# Facing problem in qml gradient orientation in 5.14 version

Tags: qt, qml, gradient

I'm working with QML gradient in *Qt 5.14*. I have created a `Rectangle` where I want to add a horizontal gradient, but *Qt 5.14* does not allow me to use some features to fix the issue.

```
Rectangle {
    id: outerRect
    width: 279
    height: 8
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    radius: 7

    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "green" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.25; color: "lightgreen" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "yellow" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.75; color: "orange" }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "red" }
    }
}
```

I can't use *Qt 5.14* above versions, so please answer the question by keeping it in mind.

I can't use `Gradient.Horizontal` or add `vertical: false` or add `rotation` as Rectangle width and height are not same.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.14/qml-qtquick-gradient.html#orientation-prop), there shouldn't be any problem here. Please also edit your post and include your final code.

Comment: The documentation says that the `orientation` property was added in 5.12. So why do you say you cannot use `Gradient.Horizontal`?

Comment: Have you tried putting your Gradient inside a LinearGradient?

Comment: I just tested your code with QtQuick 2.14 and adding `orientation: Gradient.Horizontal;` works perfectly fine: https://patrickelectric.work/qmlonline/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMALAFAkBKApujAIYB2A5gDaVwDeJc3cwAJgC44EFDEpQqNLjwDu-GAAshOAOwBOadwWVgjBTCEAOTXAboF0AM54AbuJgZazAMKV6YqELC0obmLftHFz9xEzMLKGsI4AAvCHcnV3dxLx8-PGi4hODkqBMoWj5gFEshFTIeOEYCor8hAHEa4D8OE0rK6GaEh3iGpvSACU6sumYAbjb27kbCrpgAZRgIMA44SEtgHvohAAY8HbG4dAhmaCEAImrKN3O4AF9JqZna90Xl1fXN4F64PZwAVkOx1Onjg52Yun0Vxu90e7WeczeK3YawgGy2uzwgKOJzOYIAnpRmKcZLcHlMnv1Xktkaj0d9tr88CpscC8edoAxGJQyXDKgi-EiPmivj8CPsgbjQedfHxeRTYQ8SEA

Comment: Actually I'm new to this and I was doing "Gradient.Horizontal" at top. In "gradient: Gradient.Horizontal { }" . Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @user22766422 So, if you use `orientation: Gradient.Horizontal;` *within* the `gradient: Gradient {...}` it works? If so, be aware that this is considered a "conceptual typo", as proper documentation research and studying is a mandatory requirement for StackOverflow questions, thus making your post as invalid (and, as such, off topic): we cannot cover any level of knowledge and experience, and such issues, while understandable, are not in the scope of the website, because they are too broad. I suggest you to do further research efforts on the related subjects and consider to delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you *should* be able to set orientation:

```
Gradient {
    orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you may wish to use `LinearGradient` (`import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12` in Qt5.x or `import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` in Qt6.x), for instance:

```
    Rectangle {
        id: outerRect
        width: 279
        height: 8
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        radius: 7
    }

    LinearGradient {
        anchors.fill: outerRect
        source: outerRect  
        //start: Qt.point(0, 0); end: Qt.point(0, 8) // Vertical
        start: Qt.point(0, 0); end: Qt.point(279, 0) // Horizontal
        //start: Qt.point(100, 2); end: Qt.point(180, 6) // Angled
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "green" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.25; color: "lightgreen" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "yellow" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.75; color: "orange" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "red" }
        }
    }
```

By using `LinearGradient`, you should see you have full control over the direction of your `Gradient` and you can fit it to your rectangle by setting the `start` and `end` properties to the coordinates applicatable to your `Rectangle`. Vertical, horizontal, and other angles are possible with this approach.

Comment: Note: since the OP clearly said they were using a Qt/QML version that provides the `orientation` property, we should wait for further debugging details before providing any answer. For what we know, they may be just using the enum in the wrong way (thus making the question off topic, being it a typo).